# Jsoup prevent pretty print

Tags: java, jsoup

If I do something like this with a jsoup `Element`

```
new Element("div").html("<p></p>")
```

The output of the `toString()` method (or for that case the `outerHtml()`) method yields something like this.

```
<div>
 <p></p>
</div>
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation that says it adds newlines or spaces to whatever is added to `Element`.

Is there any way to output it like that:

```
<div><p></p></div>
```

Comment: If you check the code of Elements you will see the '\n'. You have two options, either extend Element and override the outerHtml method or in the end replace something like '\n' for nothing to have a single line.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, *pretty print* settings are set on the `Document` level.

You can get and set the setting, like so:

```
// Document doc = ...
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint();      // true by default
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false); // set to false to disable "pretty print"
```

Here is how one can cook up an empty `Document`:

```java
Document doc = new Document("");
// use Jsoup.parse("") if you don't mind the basic HTML stub:
// html, head, and body.
```

This is what I would do to print your `Element` "as is" - without new lines:

```
Document doc = new Document("");
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
doc.insertChildren(0, new Element("div").html("<p></p>"));
System.out.println(doc);
// prints: <div><p></p></div>
```

---

#### References

- [`Document.OutputSettings#prettyPrint(boolean)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint(boolean))
- [`Document.OutputSettings#prettyPrint()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint())